# Circular dependency issues

Tags: binary, deb

Do some .deb binary files need each other to be installed and removed?
If so, how do you get around this?

What I observed was that I wanted to install Kodi on an offline PC, but I got stuck with installing the .deb for kodi-x11 requiring kodi-bin, and vice versa trying the other .deb.

I had to take the PC somewhere with internet and use the package installer, I selected Kodi-bin or kodi-x11 and I noticed the package manager installed kodi-x11 or kodi-bin at the same time.

If I try to uninstall one, it will say it can’t due to dependency problems siting the other. If I wanted to could I uninstall/install both simultaneously?

Thanks

Answer (score 9):

Packages can have circular dependencies, although as far as the Debian distribution itself is concerned, [this should be avoided](https://www.debian.org/doc/debian-policy/ch-relationships.html#binary-dependencies-depends-recommends-suggests-enhances-pre-depends) (and is usually treated as a bug — in `kodi`’s case, [963865](https://bugs.debian.org/963865)).

The package management tools (`dpkg`, `apt` etc.) know how to deal with circular dependencies (see the link above for details), but to do so they need to know about all the packages involved. When using `dpkg` directly, this means that all the `.deb` files need to be specified in the same `dpkg -i` invocation during installation, and all relevant packages need to be named in the same `dpkg -r` invocation during removal (in this case, `dpkg -r kodi-bin kodi-x11`). `apt` knows how to handle such removals on its own, but the same applies for offline installation: all the `.deb` files need to be specified in the same `apt install` invocation.